# mssql-scripter how to stop scripting the create database statement and remove references of source db

Tags: sql-server

I am new with mssql-scripter

I have been trying different paramters, but I can't figure out how to stop scripting the drop and create database statements(see below).
I want to run this script on an existing database, and I don't want anything in the generated script to reference the source database which the script was based.

If I am running this script on a stage db, I don't want to drop and recreate my production db.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS [dbname]
GO

 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'dbname')
 BEGIN
 CREATE DATABASE [dbname]
```

the command i am running

```
 mssql-scripter -S dbserver\SQLEXPRESS -d dbname  --exclude-use-database -- 
 check-for-existence --script-drop-create  --schema-and-data  > filename.sql
```

Comment: Can you provide the commandline that you're running now? Specifically, which arguments are you passing? Feel free to omit anything that identifies your environment (i.e. servername, username, password), but behavior controlling arguments would be helpful.

Comment: sounds good, i should have posted that before, i added the command i am running to the initial description

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found for this is that you can include the additional --include-objects parameter in your command and only specify to script out objects that are under a certain schema.

Your command can look like:

> mssql-scripter -S dbserver\SQLEXPRESS -d dbname --exclude-use-database
>   --check-for-existence --script-drop-create --schema-and-data **--include-objects "dbo."** > filename.sql

This option actually looks for the "**dbo.**" string in the fully qualified names of the database objects.